# Finding the Centroid

Tags: integration, centroid

Find the centroid of the plane area in the second quadrant bounded by the curve $x=y^2-9$.  I already computed the value of $x$ but it is $36/5$ which is positive. It should be negative because it's in the second quadrant!

Comment: I used the formula x= integral of (xsubc) * dA all over by the integral of dA from 0 to 3

Comment: The x-coordinate I solved was 36/5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $x$-coordinate of the centroid of the plane area
$$A:=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\;:\; 0\leq y \leq 3, \;y^2-9\leq x\leq 0\}$$
should be
$$\overline{x}=\frac{\int_{y=0}^3\int_{x=y^2-9}^{0}x dx dy}{\int_{y=0}^3\int_{x=y^2-9}^{0} dx dy}
=-\frac{\frac{1}{2}\int_{y=0}^3(y^2-9)^2 dy}{\int_{y=0}^3 (9-y^2) dy}
=-\frac{[\frac{y^5}{5}-6y^3+81y]_0^3}{2[9y-\frac{y^3}{3}]_0^3}
=-\frac{18}{5}.$$
Compare your computations with mine.

What is the $y$-coordinate? You should find $\overline{y}=9/8$.

Comment: I used the formula x= integral of (xsubc) * dA all over by the integral of dA from 0 to 3. My answer was x=36/5

Comment: @Del Did you find your error?

Comment: I tried to repeat but it's still 36/5

Comment: The photo was unable to upload. What formula should I use instead?

Comment: My answer for y is 27/8 is it correct?

Comment: Mine is $9/8$. I added a few steps to my computation. Compare with yours!

Comment: I got x already. I forgot to factor out the negative sign from (-y^2+9). Thanks. I'm trying y again.

Comment: I got it. Thank you :)

Comment: @Del Well done!!